# Pass an array of class objects as const to a function to prevent any modification of the class objects

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-pointer

Hi I am new to C++ and this question might be simple. Please bear with me :)

I have an array of class `Foo ==> Foo foo_objects[4];`

If I want to pass this array to a function:

```
function declaration: void do_something(Foo *foo_objects_ptr);
function call       : do_something(foo_ojects);
```

Now I want to pass this array of `foo_objects` to the function and prevent any modification of these objects.

```
function declaration: void do_something(const Foo *foo_objects_ptr);
function call       : do_something(foo_ojects);
```

Is this the right way to do it? Does this guarantee that all four objects in the `foo_objects` will be protected from any modification inside the `do_something` method or only the first object in the array enjoys `const` privileges?

Comment: Use references instead of pointers. If you need dynamic arrays, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, any access to any element through a `const` pointer will be protected from change. Unless someone gets sneaky and uses a `const_cast`, but there's no way to protect from that - C++ is designed to let you shoot yourself if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo_objects_ptr + i` has the same type as `foo_objects_ptr`, so that is also a const pointer.

So `foo_objects_ptr[i]` is const for all `i`.